# Angularjs (1.4.0-5 beta) timeout in directive only works once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout

**Problem:**

I have a directive for setting focus on an input in an HTML document. The text field, however, is hidden and activated through a certain event (for instance pressing a button). To deal with the render time a timeout is required, which works but only once.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50djdqkw/8/) for a minimal example.

Note that there's a debug print, which takes about three seconds to show the first time while it shows instantly the following times. This indicates that the timeout in fact only works once. How can I solve this problem, any help would be much appreciated!

**Code:**

HTML (HTML tag and body omitted)

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="bool = !bool">Click</button>
    <input ng-show="bool" my-focus="bool"></input>
</div>
```

AngularJS

```
var myApp = angular.module("CheckAllModule", []);

myApp.directive('myFocus', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var timer = $timeout(function () {
                scope.$watch(attr.myFocus, function (n, o) {
                    if (n != 0 && n) {
                        console.log(element[0]); // Degub print
                        element[0].focus();
                        element[0].select();
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
            element.removeAttr("my-focus");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

**Further details**

My current version of AngularJS is 1.4.0.beta-5 but the same problem persists with 1.4.0.beta-6. On Angular 1.2.1, however, there seems to be no problem.

Also when not hiding the input everything works like a charm, the directive gets called but the timeout does not.

Even on Fiddle the focus doesn't even work the first time yet it always does after hitting "run".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, if I understand your question correctly, but this focuses the input after click.

```
    var myApp = angular.module("CheckAllModule", []);

    myApp.directive('myFocus', function ($compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {          
                var focus = function (n,o) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        if (n != 0 && n) {
                            console.log(element[0]); // Degub print
                            element[0].focus();
                            element[0].select();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }

                scope.$watch(attr.myFocus, focus);

                element.removeAttr("my-focus");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        };
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much. I have been breaking my head all day about this. So I shouldn't have placed the focus inside the watch then? Could you maybe explain why? (Sorry I'm new to Angular)

Comment: Sure! `focus()` gets called every time `attr.myFocus` changes due to Angular's **Two Way Binding**. So after a click of that button, `attr.myFocus` changes and `focus()` gets fired. Now, before anything happens, it waits for 3000ms and then processes everything within the function() { if ( !=0 && ... 

So the really important part is angular **Two Way Binding** logic. Additionally, check the docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope. That may help as well.

Comment: Aaaah, I placed my timeout over the $watch which is why it only got called during 'construction' and not every time the value changed (i.e. $watch got called). Thank you so much!